# Given the function $F(x)= \int_0^x \ln(1+t)dt$, find an approximation to $F(1)= \int_0^1 \ln(1+t)dt$ with error $\varepsilon=10^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

> Given the function $F(x)= \int_0^x \ln(1+t)dt$, using MacLaurin expansion find an approximation to   $F(1)= \int_0^1 \ln(1+t)dt$ with an error that is no more than $\varepsilon=10^{-1}$

---

I am having a hard time for this topic , I will try to type what I know and tried

1. we know that the $\ln(1+t)$ expansion is $\ln (1+t)  = t - \frac{t^2} 2 + \frac{t^3} 3 - \frac{t^4}4 + \cdots$
2. I dont know if this is needed but $F(x)= \int_0^x \ln(1+t)dt=(t+1) \cdot (\ln(t+1))-(t+1)=(t+1) \cdot (\ln(t+1)-1)$
3. $F(1)= \int_0^1 \ln(1+t)dt=(2) \cdot (\ln(2)-1)$
4. The error is calculated at $R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}\cdot (x-a)^{n+1}$

5. since it is MacLaurin expansion then $R_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}\cdot (x)^{n+1}$

6. According to the Fundamental theorem of calculus the function is continuous in $[0,x]$ so $F'(x)=\ln(1+x)=f(x)$
7. we need to solve $|R_n(x)|< \varepsilon$
8. I believe this should be calculated at $t=0$ because $\ln(1+t)=\ln(1) \to t=0 $ since we know the value of $\ln(1)$ maybe we can use it as an indicator to a point (I remember my friend used to do that to find that approximation point but I am not sure why or if it is even right)

I am not sure if all points are necessary but this is what I thought about and I really don't know how to continue from here or how to actually start solving

The final answer should be $T_3(1)= \frac{1}{2!}- \frac{1}{3!} =\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taylor polynomial of degreee $n$  of $F$ at $ a = 0$ is given by

$$ P_n(x)= \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{F^{(k)}(0)}{k ! } x^k$$

Computing some derivatives :

$$ F'(x) = \ln(1+x)$$
$$ F''(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$$
$$ F'''(x) = \frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}$$
$$F^{(4)}(x) = \frac{2(1+x)}{(1+x)^4}.$$

---

The second degree Taylor polynomial is

$$ 0 + 0x + \frac{1}{2}x^2$$
The error is given by
$$ R_2(1) = \frac{F^{(3)}(c)}{3!} = \frac{1}{6} \times \frac{-1}{(1+c)^2}$$
for some $c \in (0,1)$. But there exists values of $c$ such that this error is larger than $\epsilon$ so we can't say for sure that $\vert R(1) \vert < \epsilon.$

---

We therefore look at the third degree Taylor polynomial

$$ \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{-1}{3!}x^3.$$

The remainder is given by

$$ R(1) = \frac{1}{24}\frac{2(1+c)}{(1+c)^4} = \frac{1}{12(1+c)^3}$$

for some $c \in (0,1)$. As a function of $c$ this is clearly maximum when $c = 0$. Hence the error $R(1)$ is necessarily bounded above

$$ R(1) \leq \frac{1}{12} < \epsilon.$$

Hence the third degree Taylor polynomial works for our problem. Evaluating it at $x= 1$ gives the approximation

$$ \frac{1}{2!}- \frac{1}{3!} = \frac{1}{3}$$
of $F(1) = 2\ln(2)- 2$.

We can check numerically that $F(1) \approx 0.38629$ while the approximation is $0.33333 ...$

---

> can you just please explain how you got to the conclusion that when we are using the second degree the solution is not correct?

The error at $1$ contains a number $c$. The problem is that we don't know exactly what $c$ is. We only now that it is somewhere between $(0,1)$. So if you are lucky and the true value of $c$ is near $1$ then you get the error (in absolute value) is close to $1/24 < \epsilon$. Or you could be unlucky and $c$ is close to $0$ where to error (in absolute value) is close to $1/6 > \epsilon$. So you can't be a 100% sure that the error is less than $ \epsilon.$

For the third degree we again don't know exactly what value $c$ takes but we know that regardless of the value the error will be less than $1/12 < \epsilon.$

Comment: thank you for the great detailed answer can you just please explain how you got to the conclusion that when we are using the second degree the solution is not correct?

Comment: @Adamrk See my edit for more explanation.